# Build a compile time command look up table using template metaprogramming

Tags: c++, template-meta-programming

I am trying to build a command parser for a embedded system(bare metal) where it  will receive  command via message and call corresponding function. The structure will look like

```
struct cmdparse{
    char* commandname;
    function_pointer;
};
```

Initially the respective modules will register the command they will serve and the corresponding function pointer. The command parser builds the look up table during initialisation. when ever a command is received it parses the table and calls the corresponding function, Is it possible to achieve this i.e build this look up table in compile time using template metaprogramming. The main advantage I am expecting is when ever a new command is added, I don't need to check the command parser to see if the array size needs to be increased. Since it is a embedded system project usage of vector is banned due to dynamic memory requirements. Plus if this look up table goes to ROM instead of RAM it will add a safety clause of avoiding un intentional corruption.

Comment: Only if the registering of the modules will also happen at compile-time

Comment: Yes, the command names and corresponding callbacks of will be known by the each modules at the compile time.

Answer (score 5):

If you have decent compiler (enable at least [c++11](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b11)) you can build at **compile-time** with:

```
struct cmdparse{
    const char* commandname;
    void (*fn)();
};

void whatever1();
void whatever2();

constexpr cmdparse commands[] = {//<--compiler time
  cmdparse{"cmd1", &whatever1}, 
  cmdparse{"cmd2", &whatever2}
};
```

If you don't have a good compiler you may need to remove [constexpr](/questions/tagged/constexpr) - but otherwise this method should work.

---

Making room for more commands at runtime is perhaps best done in a seperate array:

```
std::array<cmdparse, 1024> dyn_commands; //<-- supports up to 1024 commands
```

Comment: This is my existing design and, I trying to get an alternative to this. My compiler can support C++14.

Comment: @Sivaram and what is the issue with this design ? purely dynamic stuff and fixed sizes at compile time doesn't blend well together

Comment: 1) If I add a new/remove module to the project, then it requires changes in two places, corresponding module as well as this table where it is defined. 2) I cannot use static functions as call backs, I am trying to make the command parser to be more generic that this should not have any idea of commands or functions, all it should now is it is iterating over a table(which was build at compile time) and if found a match calls the function ptr.